# Parsing a complex version string

Tags: regex

I have a string that's of the following scheme:

> VersionNumber.VersionString-VersionNumber.VersionString

Such that the following example strings can be converted into arrays of information:

```
1. 1.x-2.x             => (1, 'x', '2', 'x')
2. 1.2-3.4             => (1, 2, 3, 4)
3. 1.2-3.4-beta5       => (1, 2, 3, '4-beta5')
4. 1.2-beta3-3.4       => (1, '2-beta3', 3, 4)
5. 1.2-beta3-4.5-beta6 => (1, '2-beta3', 4, '5-beta6')
```

The logic for the parse is:

1. First element is everything before the first period.
2. Second element is everything up to a hyphen immediately before a number.
3. Third element always starts with a number and is everything up to the next period.
4. Fourth element is everything after the period.

Notes:

- Second element is an arbitrary string, but will never have a hyphen that immediately precedes a number (e.g. `2-3` is not valid, but `2-beta4` is).
- Third element always starts with a number, and begins right after a hyphen.

I've been able to parse the first three cases using the following expression:

```
(.+?).(.+?)-(.+?).(.*)
```

But I'm not sure how to modify it to handle cases 4 and 5 (when the second element contains a hyphen). The two approaches I thought of were:

1. Modify the second group to match everything before a hyphen immediately preceding a digit.
2. Modify the second group to match everything until it hits a second hyphen only if the first hyphen immediately precedes a non-digit character.

Presumably the first approach is the correct/simplest way to do it, but I'm struggling with coming up with the correct regexp to express it.

Comment: Your scheme does not match your logic for the parse step 3 "Third element always starts with a number and is everything up to the next period." should your scheme be "VersionNumber.VersionString-VersionNumber.VersionString" instead of "VersionNumber.VersionString-VersionNumber-VersionString"

Comment: yeah but in your question, your scheme is Number.String-Number-String (typo?), the last hyphen is supposed to be a period me thinks, that confused me a bit.

Comment: @Joe Oh, I see it. You're right, that's a typo. Sorry, I thought you were suggesting my logic indicated I wanted "Number.String-Number-String".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can `VersionString` ever contain a dot?  If not, this should work:

```
(\d+)\.([^.]+)-(\d+)\.(\S+)
```

The `[^.]+` initially matches everything up to the next dot, but then backtracks a little bit. If `VersionString` *can* contain a dot, you can use this:

```
(\d+)\.(\S+?)-(\d+)\.(\S+)
```

Matching digits explicitly in the `VersionNumber` part serves to enforce your "digit preceded by a hyphen" rule.

(Actually, `(.+?)` works just as well; I used `(\S+?)` because I was testing the regex plucking the version strings out of the full text of your message.)

**EDIT:** Per the comments below, here's the final version:

```
(\d+[^.]*)\.(\S+?)-(\d+[^.]*)\.(\S+)
```

Comment: There's no restriction on a dot in VersionString: your second expression works great, with a slight modification: `(\d+\S*)\.(\S+?)-(\d+\S*)\.(\S+)` VersionNumber has to start with a number, but there's no restriction after that initial digit.

Comment: @Mark If there's no dot restriction in a VersionString, then a version 1.2-beta.3-4.5-beta.6 could be valid right? Unfortunately using your expression, it separates into (1.2-beta, 3, 4.5-beta, 6) instead of (1, 2-beta.3, 4, 5-beta.6)

Comment: @Joe's right, but we should be able to assume Version **Number** can't contains dots, shouldn't we?  Try `(\d+[^.]*)\.(\S+?)-(\d+[^.]*)\.(\S+)`

Comment: @Joe, Alan is right: the logic I've outlined preclude the first and third elements from having dots (first and third elements end when they reach a period). @Alan that seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(.+?)\.(.*)-(.+?)\.(.*)
```

actually, even this will work:

```
(.*)\.(.*)-(.*)\.(.*)
```

Your problem was that you were not escaping the period so it was treating it as match any char rather than match a period.

**UPDATE:**

So if a VersionString can contain periods/hyphens, following your parse logic, this should work:

```
(\d*)\.(.*)-(\d*)\.(.*)
```

It says,

1. match all numbers (matches your first VersionNumber)
2. match everything between the first period and the last hyphen before a digit (thanks to the greedy match)
3. match all digits after the hyphen but before the period
4. match the rest

The string:

```
1.2-b.e.t.a.3-4.5-b.e.t.a.6 => '1'  '2-b.e.t.a.3'   '4' '5-b.e.t.a.6'
```

It also works if you go crazy with hyphens in the versionstring too:

```
1.2-b-e.t-a.3-4.5-b-e.t-a.6 => '1'  '2-b-e.t-a.3'   '4' '5-b-e.t-a.6'
```

Comment: Ah neat, that's even simpler than the solution I came up with. Thanks!

Comment: i found this site very useful to test regex stuff, not sure if you already know about it, http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm